# PHP Simple html dom parser with array links - file_get_contents error

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a form with textarea (links one per line):

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" name="links" id="links"></textarea>
```

and the php code:

```
function scrape($link) {
  $html = file_get_html("$link");
........
}

$links = $_POST["links"];
$lines = explode("\n", $links);

foreach($lines as $line){
  scrape($line);
}
```

Error:
Warning: file_get_contents(site.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

Comment: failed to open stream

Comment: I think that the problem is with quotes.All links work.

Comment: You've sure given us a bunch of information here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a website via `file_get_contents()`; however, you need to provide the full URL to achieve that, e.g. : `http://www.example.com`. However, you may encouter problems with some pages, in which cases you could use CURL or StreamSockets to get (remote) websites.

Edit : Additionally, you should note that some OSes treat `\r\n` as what others "think" is a simple `\n`. You may try the script out with the former one; it proved to work on my Windows machine.

Comment: I do not know what happens.When I put a single link in textarea,the script work well.When i put multiple links i got this error.The url is full(include http://)

Comment: Thanks.The problem is in explode: $lines = explode("\r\n", $links);